# jQuery detects which element is visable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several tables with similar class names, but only one table is visible at a time. I am having troubles of using jQuery to detect and save the class name of the visible table (I can use .is(':visible') to check and save the class name of the positive ones, but it is kind of cumbersome.). I appreciate any suggestions.

HTML

```
<table class="tab_Chemical" border="0" style="display:none">
    <tr><th><label for="id_wat_hl">Water Column Half life (days):</label></th>
        <td><input type="text" name="wat_hl" id="id_wat_hl" /></td></tr>
</table>
<table class="tab_Physical" border="0">
    <tr><th><label for="id_mas_tras_cof">Mass Transfer Coefficient (m/s):</label></th>
        <td><input type="text" name="mas_tras_cof" value="1e-08" id="id_mas_tras_cof" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     ###CODE TO DETECT VISIBLE CLASS and SAVE the CLASS NAME###
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you just add `class="active"` to the table that is visible? This way, you can select the active table.

Comment: Selecting by class vs by :visible pseudo selector shouldn't be any different as far as it being *"kind of cumbersome"*

Comment: Actually, the visibility of those tables are changing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `:visible` pseudo-selector, along with the `^` (starts with) selector:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var visible = $("[class^='tab_']:visible");
});
```

But the starts with selector is a *little* fuzzy. If you can, give them all a common class (Good shout Kevin B)(the below assumes the class `tab` is the common class):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var visible = $(".tab:visible");
});
```

Comment: If the element could possibly have multiple classes, I'd use `[class*='tab_']`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat true, but what if it had the class `notatab_`? ;)

Comment: or possibly drop selecting by class starts with and suggest giving them a common class

Comment: @KevinB **Much** better. Giving them a common class of `tab` would be the best approach.

Comment: Then I guess you could use `.filter` and `.classList` (or `.className.split(' ')`) ^^.

Comment: @RocketHazmat True :P, but both of our approaches have been outclassed by Kevin :)

Comment: I like your second approach. I tried to use 'var visible = $(".tab:visible").attr('class');' to get the class name, but failed...

Comment: @tao.hong Did you add the `tab` class to all of the elements?

Comment: @tao.hong Try this http://jsfiddle.net/gHxn8/16/ you don't use multiple class attributes to add multiple classes, you just separate them by a space. Like so: `class="tab tab_Chemical"`

Comment: @mattytommo: thanks. Then I guess I need to parse out the second class name.

Comment: @tao.hong No problems, yeah just use `split(" ")[1]`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe:

```
var classes=[];
$("table:visible").each(function(){
   classes.push($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

Seems like an odd requirement though.  You might want to take a step back and see if there is a more logical way to do what you want.